# Angular: Using non-exported components of a module (modal)

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, ng-bootstrap

I am currently refactoring my application into much smaller modules. It seems to be a common practice, since almost all "large" ui-libraries do that (`NgBootstrap` and `NgPrime` at least).

For that, I have read the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodules) and some [guidelines](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular2-ngmodule/).

I am now putting each widget in it's own module (together with its directives, if any). Other, larger components that rely on those "base widgets" then import those, but do not export them again.

Now I have started with exporting my components that are meant to be used as modals (via `NgbModal`). I accidentally forgot to export my main component, but to my surprise... everything worked?

I do not even need to declare the component, it *still* works.

Here is a very basic [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l6kv5n?file=src/modal-test/modal-test.module.ts) (stackblitz).

Is this purely because the "code" gets loaded by importing the modal component in the `.ts` file? Apparently declarations and exports in modules are only relevant for the template parsing, in order to match the correct tags to the correct component. What are the implications of this? Should I not export components that are instantiated via code? I was unable to find a guideline about this.

Comment: That component is created dynamically. You don't need to export it. You have to export it if you want to use it within template. The downside of non-declaring that component in any of NgModule is that MyModalComponent wont notice any components or directives, e.g. try including `*ngIf` in its template

Comment: True, another drawback seems to be that when not exporting the component, the compiler does not pick up changes correctly/reliably. Are there any other things to be careful about with this? (Tree-shaking etc..)

Comment: You can put NgModule definition directly to that component and lazy load it through `import(<path>)`. But it's an advantage I guess

Comment: Ah didn't think about that, thanks. If you'd write this as a short answer I would accept it.

Comment: @yurzui Unfortunately, putting the NgModule definition with the modal directly into the component (and not specifically importing it in another module) does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by `does not work`? Can you reproduce that?

Comment: You are right, my second approach (https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-b5xfyk-ctpaoz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-a%2Fmodal-a%2Fmodal-a.component.ts) worked. I have asked another question yesterday on how to avoid circular imports and thought I'd try this suggestion, and here it does not work (https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-b5xfyk?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftrigger-a%2Ftrigger-a%2Ftrigger-a.component.ts)

Comment: Yes, another advantage of dynamic components is that they can solve circular dependency issues https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-b5xfyk-ihzhdo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmodal-b%2Fmodal-b%2Fmodal-b.component.ts

Comment: whoa, thansk. Didn't know about the injection tokens.